# Loading game does not load the position of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I've been trying to implement a savegame function into my game. When I load the game from the save, it doesn't load the position of the player.

I have 2 main scenes: The scene in which the game is taking place, and the main menu scene. The main menu makes use of my load function, which is supposed to read my save file and put the player at a given position, however, it just loads the scene at the default position. No errors are thrown, no warning messages. Here is all of my code:

This is my Save game system:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;



public static class SaveSystem 
{
    public static void SavePlayer (Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "player.fun";
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

    PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    stream.Close();
}

public static PlayerData LoadPlayer ()
{

    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
        stream.Close();
        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Save file not in " + path);
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

Container for player data:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData 
{
    public int level;
    public int health;
    public float[] position;
    public int stamina;

    public PlayerData (Player player)
    {
        level = player.level;
        health = player.health;
        stamina = player.stamina;
        position = new float[3];

        position[0] = player.transform.position.x;
        position[1] = player.transform.position.y;
        position[2] = player.transform.position.z;
    }


}
```

My Scene Changing Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool Isload = false;
    public void gotoWelwardLoad()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Welward");
        bool Isload = true;
    }
    public void gotoWelward()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Welward");
    }
    public void gotomainmenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }
}
```

My Player Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 1;
    public int stamina = 1;
    public int level = 1;

    public void SavePlayer ()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
    }

    public void LoadPlayer ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Welward");
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
        level = data.level;
        health = data.health;
        stamina = data.stamina;

        Vector3 position;
        position.x = data.position[0];
        position.y = data.position[1];
        position.z = data.position[2];
        transform.position = position;
    }

    public static void gotomenu ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public static void Welward()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Welward");
        SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
    }
}
```

Link with full unity project files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mFH5aNklC0qMWeJjMT4KD0CbTTx65VRp

Comment: The problem almost certainly can be isolated to `SaveSystem.SavePlayer()` or `SaveSystem.LoadPlayer()`, if your problem description is accurate.  Very likely you just forgot to save or load a field.

Comment: Just a simple good practice to remember, when sharing a Unity project omit uploading Library/Obj/Logs/Build folders (the same rule as for your .gitignore)

Comment: In project that you uploaded fonts are missing (so there is no text on menus). Also `ThirdPersonController` prefab is missing, how to move in your game to test save/load behaviour?

Comment: Meanwhile, your scenes hierarchy lacks in organization. There are a lot of Button, GameObject, GameObject (1) and so on stuff. Consider naming them to keep organized. For example, LoadButton, SaveButton, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What exactly do you mean by "Very likely you just forgot to save or load a field"?

Answer (score 1):

As [BugFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder) correctly points out, your save path is different than your loading path.

Try changing `Application.persistentDataPath + "player.fun";` to `Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";` to match your loading code. Or you could move that `string path` variable up into the class as a const then reference it since it will be guaranteed to match.

After that however you will also need to call `Player.LoadPlayer()` somewhere since in your existing project you do not do that anywhere I can find, and when you call it currently it will reload the scene (which probably isn't the behaviour you want either). I would remove `SceneManager.LoadScene("Welward");` from that method.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    // This is a way to make sure your path is the same, and not about to get overwritten
    public static string Path => Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";

    public static void SavePlayer (Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();

        // It's helpful to print out where this is going
        Debug.Log($"Wrote to {Path}");
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer ()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            // It's also helpful to print out that it worked, not just log errors if it fails
            Debug.Log($"Successfully read from {Path}");
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not in " + Path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I didn't see that. I will try it immediately, using Bug Finder's preferred "Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"player.fun");" Function as opposed to the current solution. Also, I have to change scenes as my LoadPlayer function is being called from the main menu, which then loads the worldspace.

Comment: `SaveSystem.LoadPlayer()` is called from your menu, but `Player.LoadPlayer()` is never called that I can see. `Player.LoadPlayer()` should probably be called since that's where you apply the position from the save file to the Player's transform.

Answer (score 0):

One thing thats noticeable is in save you use `Application.persistentDataPath + "player.fun";` and in load you use, `Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";`  So, perhaps therefore it doesnt find the file to load it. As you thought.  Personally Path.Combine is a good option, platform non specific etc. So try replacing both with `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"player.fun");`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided I don't see the part where you call `Player.LoadPlayer()`. So add it to Player:

```
void Start(){
    LoadPlayer();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I call it inside of unity using the onclick function of a button in my start menu.

Comment: @LeeJordan wait you call it before loading next scene?